# PowerShell commands not available over SSH

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ssh, powershell

I am using OpenSSH to connect from a Windows 10 machine to another Windows 10 machine.

***Why on the target machine I am not able to execute PowerShell commands, but only commands that are available in Command shell (cmd)?***

For example with the same client of OpenSSH when I am connecting to a Linux machine, I am able to run Bash. Is cmd the default ssh shell for Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, run `powershell` as the first command to drop into the powershell shell. The default windows cli (what you know as CMD) cannot interpret powershell commands.

Comment: Oh my God, you are a genius! Running `powershell` as the first command allowed me to send ps commands to the machine, how simple was that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @meJustAndrew You're quite welcome. Glad it helped you out.